# WPF Button with context menu, How to bind context menu width to width of the button?

Tags: wpf, binding

I've got a simple button where I want the context menu's width to be the same width as the button (I'm making the left click of the button open the context menu directly below the button).

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="Push Me">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="cm">
            <MenuItem Header="One" />
            <MenuItem Header="Two" />
            <MenuItem Header="Three" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

I've tried the following binding on the context menu itself and it doesn't work

```
<ContextMenu x:Name="cm" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
```

But, I've been able to get it working in code

```
btn.LayoutUpdated += (s, e) => cm.Width = btn.ActualWidth;
```

My question is... Does a xaml binding exist that will get me this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ContextMenu` has a Property called `PlacementTarget` which in this case will be the `Button` so you can try to use in the Path for the `Binding`

```
<ContextMenu x:Name="cm"
             Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                             Path=PlacementTarget.ActualWidth}">
```

Comment: @Jon Keep in mind anything outside of the PlacementTarget (Button) will have to resort to searching the visual tree...thus adjusting the NameScope but this solution is certainly ideal for your scenario.

Comment: @Aaron, got it, this will only get me access to the Button but if I wanted to get to a parent StackPanel or something then I need to search the tree.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the way in which the `ContextMenu` behaves with regard to its `NameScope`. If you analyze the `ContextMenu` in the debugger you willl note its parent is a `Popup` and the parent of the `Popup` is null.

One of the [workarounds](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/A09D3EDB-9402-43BA-9638-1322E4D834BE) noted on the MSDN forums is to adjust the `NameScope` which will then allow the `ContextMenu` to behave as you would expect.

```
    NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());
```

This is obviously going to take place in the code behind as is your other approach; neither being optimal.

Comment: thanks for the insight, this is my first wpf experience and i need all the insight i can get =)

Comment: +1 for your answer as well, I didn't know you could set the NameScope like that, good to know!